# Internet Explorer's Weird Behavior With PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server, internet-explorer

I have a php code `list.php` working differently on Internet Explorer 9, 10, 11 and chrome.

I'm listing pagination using `<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?no=$next_list>`. 
In Chrome and IE 11, this code works fine, which means when I click the link I am directed to `mydomainname.com/list.php?no=10`.

But in IE 9 and 10, I am directed to `list.php?no=10` and am encountered by 'page not found' error. In other words, I am directed to a solid 'file name' instead of 'domain address + file name'.

Another behavior I noticed in IE 9 and 10 before I click the pagination link is that the address reads `mydomainname.com//list.php`.

I've included html5shiv.js and respond.js for IE performances.

Is it something like $_SERVER or PHP_SELF not configured properly for old IE? I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm failing to hold myself back from saying "don't use IE and don't use PHP"!

Comment: Browsers do not process PHP code; they process the HTML code that they get from a server (which may have generated it with PHP). Show a reproducible case, preferably a minimalized HTML document. After finding out the cause at the HTML level, it’s time to look at the PHP code and figure out how it needs to be modified.

Comment: But the problem is it only behaves wrong with IE 9 and 10. Shouldnt it be a compatibility problem of old IE versions then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href=/$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?no=$next_list>
```

note the "/" - this will bring you always back to root

Is that what you mean?

Comment: What I mean is... Say I am in a page 'google.com/list.php'. A link `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` directs me to 'google.com/list.php' in Chrome and IE 11. Whereas in IE10 and 9, it directs me to 'list.php', which is not a valid address. I tried your suggestion, putting `/` in front, but it directe me to 'google.com/list.php' even with chrome and IE11 as IE10,9 did. IE...Its a pain....

Comment: You said: "I tried your suggestion, putting / in front, but it directe me to 'google.com/list.php'" isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$next_list = 12;

?>
<body>
    <?php echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?no=$next_list>test</a>"; ?>
</body>
```

I couldn't reproduce the issue with the above test code, maybe you have a link to provide ?